# Strengthening or consequence of Goldbach?

Tags: prime-numbers, goldbachs-conjecture

Is the conjecture that every integer $n \equiv 2 \bmod{4}$ greater than $6$ can be expressed as the sum of two primes of the form $4n+3$ a strengthening, or a consequence of Goldbach?

Comment: Neither nor. It does not follow from Goldbach, I think, but also it is not a strengthening, because it does not strengthen the case $n\equiv 0 \bmod 4$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde thanks - answered at exactly that same time as quid! :)

Comment: Do you check this conjecture? How far?

Comment: @MichaelGaluza not that far (to $50 000$), but the comet seems similar in nature to the original Goldbach with a highly speculative lower bound (if conjecture is correct) of $\frac{n}{4 \log ^2(n)}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is neither a strengthening nor a consequence.

- A number congruent $2$ modulo $4$ could also be the sum of two primes that are congruent to $1$ modulo $4$. Your condition excludes this latter possibility. So it cannot follow from Goldbach.
- Your conjecture says nothing about number congruent $0$ modulo $4$ and there is no way (at least no apparent one) to get them as sums from your assertion.

However, your conjecture should be at a similar level of difficulty as the Goldbach conjecture; likely slightly harder.

Note though that every number congruent $6$ modulo $8$ is a sum of two primes congruent to $3$ modulo $4$ would be a consequence of Goldbach's conjecture, as  a representation of such a number as a sum of two primes cannot involve a prime congruent $1$ modulo $4$.

Comment: You are welcome! I include a staement similar to your that would be a consequence of the Golbach conjecture.

Comment: usually I would leave it some time before the accept, but there seems little more to add, so accepted :)